# querying and sorting data in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating project using php and showing data on my page using mysql query.Now i need to fetch everytime 10 records and sorted according to image comes first.

What i want to achieve is:

**Fetch data from DB and sort by image field, means the data who have valid image path and not null.**

Also some images have path but the image does not present on that path also needs to be sorted

Here is the Query:

```
$producteviews=  DB::select("SELECT eqr.buyerName As pBuyer,eqr.userImage, eqr.description As reviewDescription,eq.* 
FROM equipments_review As eqr 
     INNER JOIN equipments As eq ON eq.id=eqr.equipment_id 
Where eqr.status = '1' ORDER by  eqr.created_at DESC limit ".$id.",10");
```

This query getting the data according to date and gives 10 records, bu i need to get and sort the data according to valid conditions

Comment: MySQL don't know anything about the actual images. If the path is incorrect or doesn't exist, then you need some PHP magic to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

In your select query, and an `IS NOT NULL` where condition. Assuming that your image field is `eqr.userImage`, then it would look like this:

```
$producteviews=  DB::select("SELECT eqr.buyerName As pBuyer,eqr.userImage, eqr.description As reviewDescription,eq.* FROM equipments_review As eqr INNER JOIN equipments As eq ON eq.id=eqr.equipment_id Where eqr.status = '1' AND eqr.userImage IS NOT NULL ORDER by  eqr.created_at DESC limit ".$id.",10");
```

In the above query, I have copied the statement in question and added the `IS NOT NULL` to show usage.